# Unable to install package libnetcdf6 in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, dpkg, dependencies

I would like to install the package libenetcdf6 in ubuntu 14.04, when i install it , i am incurring  following error, kindly let me know how could i possibly solve this problem

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libnetcdf6:
 libnetcdf6 depends on libhdf5-serial-1.8.4 | libhdf5-1.8.4; however:
  Package libhdf5-serial-1.8.4 is not installed.
  Package libhdf5-1.8.4 is not installed.
 libnetcdfc7 (1:4.1.3-7ubuntu2) breaks libnetcdf6 (<< 1:4.1.1-7~) and is installed.
  Version of libnetcdf6 to be configured is 1:4.1.1-6.
 libnetcdfc++4 (1:4.1.3-7ubuntu2) breaks libnetcdf6 (<< 1:4.1.1-7~) and is installed.
  Version of libnetcdf6 to be configured is 1:4.1.1-6.

dpkg: error processing package libnetcdf6 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libnetcdf6
```

Comment: Did any of the answers help you? If yes, mark it as an answer so that others may refer it and the person gets some reputation points..

Answer (score 0):

Are there packages that need updating? If so do the following first and then try again..

```
sudo apt-get update        # Fetches the list of available updates
sudo apt-get upgrade       # Strictly upgrades the current packages
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade  # Installs updates (new ones)
```

Answer (score 0):

On your terminal(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>), run the following command after the dpkg command to install dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```